# Installed modules not found by Python

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I need to use the `autogui` module to do something in Python. When I run the script, it says that it can't find the `autogui` module so I installed it with
`pip install autogui`.
But when I run the script again it still says me this module doesn't exist.

Comment: Please share the stack trace of this error. It is most likely an issue with your `PYTHONPATH`. Alternatively, you can share the output from `import sys; print(sys.path)` Thanks!

Comment: you might be pip installing for a different python version than the one that's running your script. What's the output of `pip --version` and `python --version`?

Comment: sys.path: "['c:\\Users\\Reno\\Documents\\Gaby\\VS Code', 'C:\\Users\\Reno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Reno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Reno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Reno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\Reno\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']"  and pip version: pip 20.2.4 from C:\Users\Reno\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip

Comment: what IDE or Text editor are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

Try `pyautogui` - I had the same problem. Instead of `autogui`, write `pyautogui. Or, if you are running python3 or higher then try:

```
pip3 install pyautogui.
```

Comment: Sorry for the imprecision, I meant the « pyautogui » module

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

You're probably having trouble setting up your correct Python Interpreter and working within it,try the following in VSCode.

> Ctrl + Shift + p

And enter the following in the field.

> python: select interpreter

Select the desired environment and reinstall **PyAutoGui**

Method 2:

Creating a virtual environment for your project where all your packages will be installed and will be isolated from others, and will have no import errors since it's an environment specifically for the project that you're working on.

I assume you use Windows, so open the command line in your working directory, or open your working directory in VSCode and enter the following in the command-line tool that is provided within VSCode.

The Python installers for Windows include pip. You should be able to access pip using:

> py -m pip --version

You can make sure that pip is up-to-date by running the following

> py -m pip install --upgrade pip

Installing virtual environment

> py -m pip install --user virtualenv

Creating a virtual environment

> py -m venv env

The second argument is the location to create the virtual environment. Generally, you can just create this in your project and call it env.

venv will create a virtual Python installation in the env folder.

Finally, to activate the environment run the following command

> .\env\Scripts\activate

That will activate your environment.

> pip install pyautogui

Make sure to change your interpreter to the one that you just created in the **env/bin** folder and run your code, or you could just enter the path to the **python* file located in the **env/bin** folder.